# Nodejs and callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x

I am very new to Node.js and how it's callbacks work exactly, I am trying to find some good documentation on it but it's just not clicking for me yet. I'm coming from python so I'll show an example of what I'm use to doing in python, I'm not sure if it's possible in node though

```
def getRequest(link):
    url = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read().decode()
    return url

class urlData:
     def __init__(self, link):
         self.results = getRequest(link)
```

I'm not sure if node can do this because it's async ways, or is it possible? I'm not sure how to go about this the correct way, how would I replicate this action in node? If not can the this code be toyed with to get similar results, a way to set the variable with the data that is going to come?

Answer (score 0):

The way you might do this in node is the following:

Install Request. https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var request = require('request');
```

Now we have a simple http client.

```
 var data;
 request.get({url:url, json:true}, function (e, r, body) {
   // this will get called when the response returns.  Your app will continue before this is called.
  data = body;  // i have no idea what you want to do with it
  console.log(body);  // should be json
})
```

Comment: Well, I don't really want to print the body or information being received I just want to set the data as a variable to use for later, but thank you for answering I will look into the documentation on that request module and see if it has anything explaining how to set a variable with information

Comment: The console is for demonstration purposes only. Your app will be doing something with it.  What, I have idea which is why it is common to put a console.log in an answer.